# Различные цвета JS и CSS в HTML-файлах, открытых редактором Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text

Как сделать так, чтобы, например, когда я открываю HTML-файл, в котором есть JS и, например, CSS, сразу становилось бы видно, где JS, где СSS, где HTML. Например, под HTML — стандартный (серый) бэкграунд, под JS — белый, а под СSS — зелёный.

Думаю, суть объяснил. Помню, что была такая настройка — а сейчас она оооочень нужна, — только не могу её найти.

Comment: Неплохо, конечно, `Sublime` пропиарился.

Answer (score 4):

**Сложное решение**

Создание собственного синтаксиса через YAML файлы, где даже чтобы подсветить отдельное слово, [потребуется немало действий и навыков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/503513/199934).

**Простое решение**

Открываем файл своей активной цветовой схемы,  по умолчанию — Monokai. Если не знаете, какая у вас установлена, <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Color Scheme</kbd> → <kbd>Color Scheme Default</kbd> (в выпадающем меню могут быть и другие пункты, в случае, когда по переходу на <kbd>Color Scheme Default</kbd> нигде нет галочки, ищем галочку по ним) → отмеченная галочкой и есть ваша схема.

Установив плагин [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer), открываем файл схемы: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> → <kbd>PackageResourseViewer:Open Resourse</kbd> (благодаря [fuzzy поиску](https://habrahabr.ru/post/147856/) можно набрать просто `prvor`) → <kbd>Color Scheme Default</kbd> (если ваша цветовая схема оказалась в другой папке, выберите эту самую папку) → выбираем файл схемы с расширением `.tmTheme` .

Допустим, в HTML файлах мы хотим подсветить оранжевым JavaScript, фиолетовым CSS, а в качестве общей подсветки, когда не заданы конкретные значения, выбрать насыщенный розовый (в примере им подсвечено `widget_id`). Куда-нибудь между тегами `<array></array>` нашей цветовой схемы вставляем код:

```
  <!-- Общая подсветка фона элементов -->
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Default source</string>
            <key>scope</key>
            <string>text source, string.unquoted</string>
            <key>settings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>background</key>
                <string>#E07585E0</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>

  <!-- JS в html документах -->
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>JS source</string>
            <key>scope</key>
            <string>source.js.embedded.html</string>
            <key>settings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>background</key>
                <string>#7A4A2299</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>

  <!-- CSS в html документах -->
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>CSS source</string>
            <key>scope</key>
            <string>source.css.embedded.html, meta.attribute-with-value.style.html source.css</string>
            <key>settings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>background</key>
                <string>#804A7D99</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

Вероятно в файле вашей схемы уже присутствуют какие-то из областей видимости (см. ниже) `text source`, `string.unquoted`, `source.js.embedded.html`, `source.css.embedded.html`, `meta.attribute-with-value.style.html`, `source.css`. Тогда смените цвет, принимаемый соответствующими областями видимости, на указанный в коде между тегами `<string></string>`, идущими в следующей за `<key>background</key>` строке. Формат — [ARGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space#ARGB_.28word-order.29).

Результат. Обратите внимание на мини-карту, стало удобнее ориентироваться.

[image: Различная подсветка JS и CSS]

Разберём синтаксис:

- В строках вроде `<string>#804A7D99</string>` `#804A7D99` — цвет. Если вас не устроили предложенные мной, впишите те, которые вам придутся по душе.
- `background` — фон. Если вместо `background` мы пропишем `foreground`, изменится цвет самого текста, а не бэкграунда вокруг него.

Представленные далее параметры называются «scopes» (я перевёл как «области видимости», за точность перевода не ручаюсь):

<-- *`string.unquoted` — поле объекта строки без кавычек в javascript, можете удалить из кода. Привёл его для примера, чтобы наглядно видели розовую подсветку на скриншоте.* -->

- `text source` — общий хайлайт, когда не заданы конкретные значения.
- `source.js.embedded.html` и `source.css.embedded.html` — JavaScript и CSS соответственно в `HTML` документах.  Файлы с расширениями `.js` и `.css` останутся без подсветки, при желании обратного вместо `source.js.embedded.html` и `source.css.embedded.html` вписать `source.js` и `source.css`. Ну и если вдруг потребуется хайлайт HTML, область видимости HTML — `text.html` .
- `meta.attribute-with-value.style.html source.css` — [встроенные стили CSS](http://seodon.ru/css/podkluchenie-css.php), подсвечиваться будет фон значения атрибута *`.style`* . `source.css` после пробела означает, что у инлайнового CSS подсветка такая же, как у заключённого в тег `<style></style>`.  Обратите внимание, что области видимости можно перечислять через запятую.

[image: Встроенные стили CSS]

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>View</kbd> -> <kbd>Syntax</kbd> -> <kbd>HTML</kbd>/<kbd>CSS</kbd>/<kbd>JS</kbd>

Comment: @0xdb да вроде бы это не вопрос, а ответ, просто с вопросительным знаком в конце.

Comment: Valeriia, я проверил ваш способ. У меня там есть только отдельные пункты HTML, CSS и JS, но нет комбинации. А автор спрашивает именно про комбинацию кода на разных языках в одном файле. У вас такое работает?

Answer (score -1):

Заходишь в Preferences -> Color Scheme и выбираешь нужную схему, например Dawn.

Comment: да не - это не то, это для всего саблайма ставится тема, а мне нужно - для конкретных ЯП ( что -то по типу плагина )