# Подсветка закрывающихся тегов (Highlighting matching tags Sublime Text)

Tags: sublime-text

Возможно ли кастомизировать подстветку закрывающихся тегов в Sublime Text 3 подобно тому, как на скриншоте ниже(Так реализовано в Brackets)?.
Есть плагин для этих целей BracketHighlighter (https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter), но перебрав имеющиеся конфиги, не

[image: Пример подсветки тегов]

Comment: заинтригован станиславский боится выйти в туалет…

Comment: О настройках плагина BracketHighlighter см. [здесь](http://montesjmm.com/2012/09/19/sublime-text-2-bracket-highlighter/). Опции плагина в `Preferences` → `Package Settings` → `Bracket Highlighter` → `Bracket Settings - Default`. Если не нашли нужной Вам функции, конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, свой вопрос. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подчерк, а не подсветка тегов и скобок в Sublime Text 3 реализовывается без плагинов.

Для начала на всякий случай кликаем на <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Settings - User</kbd> , в открывшийся файл между `{}` добавляем следующие строки:

```
"match_brackets": true,
"match_brackets_angle": true,
"match_brackets_square": true,
"match_brackets_braces": true,
"match_brackets_content":true,
"match_tags": true,
```

Сохраняем. В Sublime Text 3 всем этим параметрам кроме `match_brackets_angle` присвоено значение `true`, но мало ли, в последующих сборках могут и поменять на `false`. `match_brackets` — подчёркивание различных [разновидностей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8) скобок, `match_tags` — подчерк тегов.

Далее открываем файл привычной цветовой схемы с расширением `tm.Theme`. В самом его начале находим примерно следующие строки ( значения цветов могут отличаться от приведённых в примере):

```
<key>lineHighlight</key>
<string>lightslategray</string>
<key>foreground</key>
<string>#ffdab9</string>
<key>invisibles</key>
<string>#BFBFBF</string>
<key>selection</key>
<string>dimgray</string>
```

Где-нибудь между ними до закрывающих тегов `</dict>` вставляем следующие теги:

```
            <key>bracketContentsForeground</key>
            <string>yellow</string>
                <key>bracketContentsOptions</key>
                <string>underline</string>
            <key>bracketsForeground</key>
            <string>cyan</string>
                <key>bracketsOptions</key>
                <string>squiggly_underline</string>
            <key>tagsForeground</key>
            <string>lawngreen</string>
                <key>tagsOptions</key>
                <string>underline</string>
```

Пояснения:

- `bracketContentsForeground` — цвет подчёркивания любых скобок, между которыми расположена каретка. Между тегами `<string></string>` вписывается цвет, лучше в формате [HEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet), чем [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names), поскольку в Sublime Text могут возникнуть проблемы как минимум с отображением цветов `aqua`, `fuchsia` и `lime`.
- `bracketContentsOptions` — стиль подчёркивания скобок, между которыми расположена каретка. Значения: `underline` — подчерк прямой линией, `stippled_underline` — пунктирной, `squiggly_underline` — волнистой. По умолчанию `underline`.

[image: Подчерк любых скобок]

- `bracketsForeground` — цвет подчёркивания скобок, когда рядом со скобками расположена каретка.  Между тегами `<string></string>` вписывается цвет.
- `bracketsOptions` — стиль подчёркивания скобок, рядом с которыми расположена каретка. Значения: `underline` — подчерк прямой линией, `stippled_underline` — пунктирной, `squiggly_underline` — волнистой. По умолчанию `underline`.

[image: Подчерк скобок, когда около них каретка]

- `tagsForeground` — цвет подчёркивания тегов. Когда каретка находится внутри тега, подчёркивается как он сам, так и соответствующий ему открывающий/закрывающий тег.
- `tagsOptions` — стиль подчёркивания тегов. Значения: `underline` — подчерк прямой линией, `stippled_underline` — пунктирной, `squiggly_underline` — волнистой. По умолчанию `stippled_underline` .

[image: Подчерк тегов в Sublime Text 3]

Мне этого вполне хватает. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Лучше, чем [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513566/199934), воспользоваться плагином [BracketHighlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter).

[Частая](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15662179/5951529) проблема — скобки и кавычки как в коде, так и gutter (полоса, где номера строк) подсвечиваются тем же цветом, что и текст. Чтобы её исправить, необходимо:

1. <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Package Settings</kbd> → <kbd>BracketHighlighter</kbd> → <kbd>Bracket Settings - User</kbd> → в открывшийся файл вставляем следующий код → сохраняем файл.

   ```
   {
   "bracket_styles": {
       // This particular style is used to highlight
       // unmatched bracket pairs. It is a special
       // style.
       "unmatched": {
           "icon": "question",
           "color": "brackethighlighter.unmatched",
           "style": "highlight"
       },
       // User defined region styles
       "curly": {
           "icon": "curly_bracket",
           "color": "brackethighlighter.curly",
           "style": "highlight"
       },
       "round": {
           "icon": "round_bracket",
           "color": "brackethighlighter.round",
           "style": "outline"
       },
       "square": {
           "icon": "square_bracket",
           "color": "brackethighlighter.square",
           "style": "outline"
       },
       "angle": {
           "icon": "angle_bracket",
           "color": "brackethighlighter.angle",
           "style": "outline"
       },
       "tag": {
           "icon": "tag",
           "color": "brackethighlighter.tag",
           "style": "outline"
       },
       "single_quote": {
           "icon": "single_quote",
           "color": "brackethighlighter.quote",
           "style": "outline"
       },
       "double_quote": {
           "icon": "double_quote",
           "color": "brackethighlighter.quote",
           "style": "outline"
       },
       "regex": {
           "icon": "regex",
           "color": "brackethighlighter.quote",
           "style": "outline"
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. В файл своей цветовой схемы с расширением *tmTheme* (если не знаете, как его открыть, см. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516033/199934) в самом начале) где-нибудь между тегами `<array></array>` вставляем следующие строки:

   ```
   <!-- BracketHighlighter -->
   <!-- BracketHighlighter: Вопросительный знак, если BracketHighlighter не находит, с чем сопоставлена скобка, а также текст внутри несопоставленного открывающего/закрывающего тега -->
   <dict>
       <key>name</key>
       <string>Unmatched</string>
       <key>scope</key>
       <string>brackethighlighter.unmatched</string>
       <key>settings</key>
       <dict>
           <key>foreground</key>
           <string>#FD971F</string>
       </dict>
   </dict>
   <!-- BracketHighlighter: фигурные скобки -->
   <dict>
       <key>name</key>
       <string>BracketHighlighter: Curly</string>
       <key>scope</key>
       <string>brackethighlighter.curly</string>
       <key>settings</key>
       <dict>
           <key>foreground</key>
           <string>#FF0000</string>
       </dict>
   </dict>
   <!-- BracketHighlighter: круглые скобки -->
   <dict>
       <key>name</key>
       <string>BracketHighlighter: Round</string>
       <key>scope</key>
       <string>brackethighlighter.round</string>
       <key>settings</key>
       <dict>
           <key>foreground</key>
           <string>lightblue</string>
       </dict>
   </dict>
   <!-- BracketHighlighter: квадратные скобки -->
   <dict>
       <key>name</key>
       <string>BracketHighlighter: Square</string>
       <key>scope</key>
       <string>brackethighlighter.square</string>
       <key>settings</key>
       <dict>
           <key>foreground</key>
           <string>pink</string>
       </dict>
   </dict>
   <!-- BracketHighlighter: угловые скобки -->
   <dict>
       <key>name</key>
       <string>BracketHighlighter: Angle</string>
       <key>scope</key>
       <string>brackethighlighter.angle</string>
       <key>settings</key>
       <dict>
           <key>foreground</key>
           <string>#FEFE22</string>
       </dict>
   </dict>
   <!-- BracketHighlighter: скобки тегов (пока не знаю, что за тегов) -->
   <dict>
       <key>name</key>
       <string>BracketHighlighter: Bracket Tag</string>
       <key>scope</key>
       <string>brackethighlighter.tag</string>
       <key>settings</key>
       <dict>
           <key>foreground</key>
           <string>violet</string>
       </dict>
   </dict>
   <!-- BracketHighlighter: одинарные и двойные скобки, (ещё где-то регулярные выражения) -->
   <dict>
       <key>name</key>
       <string>BracketHighlighter: Single Quote | Double Quote | Regex</string>
       <key>scope</key>
       <string>brackethighlighter.quote</string>
       <key>settings</key>
       <dict>
           <key>foreground</key>
           <string>palegreen</string>
       </dict>
   </dict>
   ```

Между тегами `<string></string>` под `<key>foreground</key>` меняем цвета, как душе угодно. Лучше прописывать их в [HEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet), а не [X11 colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names), поскольку в Sublime Text 3 могут некорректно отображаться как минимум цвета `aqua`, `fuchsia` и `lime`.

Скобки, кавычки и их выделения в тексте должны получиться разноцветными:

[image: Настроенный BracketHighlighter]

Comment: Добрый вечер! Скажите, пожалуйста, а как сделать, чтобы и остальное выделялось жирным, как - `{}`. А то в глаза не бросается для меня:)