# Проблема с подсветкой синтаксиса в Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Всем привет!
У меня проблема с подсветкой синтаксиса в Sublime Text 3...

Установил модуль [Bracket​Highlighter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter) , для подсветки синтаксиса HTML.
И он достаточно странно работает...
[image]
Он подсвечивает только само название тега без угловых скобок...
Хотелось бы чтобы он работал таким образом:
[image]
Спасибо.

```
{
"bracket_styles": {
    // This particular style is used to highlight
    // unmatched bracket pairs. It is a special
    // style.
    "unmatched": {
        "icon": "question",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.unmatched",
        "style": "highlight"
    },
    // User defined region styles
    "curly": {
        "icon": "curly_bracket",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.curly",
        "style": "highlight"
    },
    "round": {
        "icon": "round_bracket",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.round",
        "style": "outline"
    },
    "square": {
        "icon": "square_bracket",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.square",
        "style": "outline"
    },
    "angle": {
        "icon": "angle_bracket",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.angle",
        "style": "outline"
    },
    "tag": {
        "icon": "tag",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.tag",
        "style": "outline"
    },
    "single_quote": {
        "icon": "single_quote",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.quote",
        "style": "outline"
    },
    "double_quote": {
        "icon": "double_quote",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.quote",
        "style": "outline"
    },
    "regex": {
        "icon": "regex",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.quote",
        "style": "outline"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [На гитхабе уже есть тикет](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/issues/377) по мотивам вашего вопроса.

Comment: Основная проблема с таким поведением, насколько я понимаю, состоит в том, что тег может состоять не только из названия и скобочек, но ещё и атрибутов и их значений. На отдельные компоненты у него отдельные матчеры, и [**подсветка только имени тега вбита в код гвоздями**](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/blob/master/bh_modules/tags.py#L61). Похоже, что потребуется Python, конфигами дело не обойдётся.

Comment: А возможно ли что это баг модуля?

Comment: Я думаю, что это таки **фича** модуля. В комментарии по ссылке явно написано, что это задуманное поведение. Можете начать с модификации пакета путём убирания [вот этих строчек](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/blob/master/bh_modules/tags.py#L63-L72). Но это игра в угадайку, я понятия не имею, что при этом произойдёт %)

Comment: Тогда немного странная фича)))
Так как на картинке показана одна работа)))
А на деле другая, и нигде не указано как сделать, чтобы оно работало как на картинке)
Я ставил модуль ради того, чтобы оно работало как на картинке xD

Comment: php_array, уточните, нужно ли Вам выделение атрибутов тегов, как [**здесь**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wXt0L.png). Спасибо.

Comment: @php_array действительно, на картинке в репозитории показан ваш вариант. Возможно, он из старой-старой версии. Но я не в курсе :)

Comment: @Саша Черных Не могу загрузить картинку...

Comment: @Саша Черных Да, данный вариант вполне устраивает)

Comment: php_array, это особенность плагинов ув-мого facelessuser, юзабилити которых, к сожалению, не такое, какое хотелось бы. Установил — начинай работать — это отнюдь не о плагинах данного разработчика. Будьте готовы к тому, что Вам часами придётся вручную настраивать параметры и читать документацию. Причём без скриншотов/скринкастов, поэтому придётся экспериментировать со значениями параметров. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Покопавшись в реализации, **я нашёл дыру в конфигурационном файле**.
**Она не задокументирована и может исчезнуть в любой момент, а также лишает возможности настроить другую вещь**, но это работает на данный момент.

Найдите конфигурационный файл для тегов:

- Preferences (в строке меню)
- Package Settings
- BracketHighlighter
- Tag Settings – User

...и внесите в настройки следующее:

```
{
  "tag_style": {"html": null}
}
```

**Всё. Сохраняйте и пробуйте.**

Но если вам интересно, как так получилось...

---

## Какого?..

Дело в том, что автор пакета изначально подсвечивал тег целиком. И картинка в репозитории ещё с тех времён. Но его это раздражало и он сузил подсветку только до названия тега.

**И как сознательный программист он сделал это [отдельной функцией](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/blob/master/bh_modules/tags.py#L61-L73)**, аккуратно встроив её в нужное место. В неё передаётся диапазон `left`-`right`, в котором размещён элемент подлежащий подсветке, функция сужает его до того, какой именно кусочек надо подсветить и возвращает.

```py
def highlighting(view, name, style, left, right):
    """Highlight only the tag name."""
    tag_settings = sublime.load_settings("bh_tag.sublime-settings")
    match_style = tag_settings.get("tag_style", {}).get(last_mode, None)
    if match_style is not None and style == match_style:
        tag_name = tag_settings.get('tag_name', {}).get(last_mode, '[\w\:\.\-]+')
        if left is not None:
            region = view.find(tag_name, left.begin)
            left = left.move(region.begin(), region.end())
        if right is not None:
            region = view.find(tag_name, right.begin)
            right = right.move(region.begin(), region.end())
    return left, right
```

Я было закомментировал всё содержимое этой функции кроме последней строки, чтобы диапазон возвращался нетронутым. И это сработало. Но потом я обратил внимание, что сужение уже спрятано в `if` и заинтересовался, нельзя ли оборвать его.

Как оказалось, можно. Можно заставить `match_style` оказаться `None`, поскольку его значение берётся напрямую из конфигурации. Описанная выше процедура его и подменяет.

Покопавшись, вы можете собрать версию этого пакета без сужения, закомментировав в этой функции всё, кроме `return left, right`. Тогда хак в конфигурационном файле не потребуется. [Установка модифицированных пакетов не слишком сложна](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/customizing_packages).

Можете даже форкнуть пакет, совершить в нём изменение и установить прямо с гитхаба через Package Control с помощью "Add Repository". Лицензия MIT не запрещает это делать.

Comment: Может, pull-request сделаете?

Comment: @СашаЧерных не возьмусь. (а) Я не знаю Python приблизительно совсем. (б) Я не знаю, не взрывают ли описанные изменения что-нибудь где-нибудь ещё.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.
Теперь было бы круто как то это все в "outline" засунуть.
Это можно сделать через стили самой цветовой темы?

Comment: @php_array штатный способ настройки стилей тегов при использовании этого хака как раз и ломается. Поэтому если вас не устраивает стиль по умолчанию, придётся делать модифицированный пакет, убирая вышеописанные строчки.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, но кажись автор этого модуля запланировал такое поведение...
[Тут его слова...](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/issues/377)
Но я не могу быть уверен в правильности своего перевода, так как я плохо знаю английский...

Пожалуйста, объясните, правильно ли я понял?

> Make sure that template gets followed when creating an issue on this repo. Eventually, all of my repos will follow a similar pattern. I appreciate the clearness of expected vs actual, but it is also helpful for me to get info such as BracketHighlighter version and such as that can be critical in helping to solve bugs.
>
> "I don't understand, how I can highlight angle brackets in tags."
>
>
> To answer your question now. The main picture on the readme does show the entire tag being highlighted. That was from a much earlier version of bracket highlighter. It became kind of annoying having the entire tag highlighted (attributes and all). So a change was made directly in the tag module to just highlight the tag name to be a little more less annoying. It is a bit more low profile, but it is also less distracting than when it was encompassing the entire tag with attributes.
>
> Unfortunately, it is not configurable. Ideally, I should update the main image to reflect the current behavior.

Comment: То есть, я был таки прав. Картинка просто из старинной версии. Обводка всего тега несколько раздражала и он ограничил подсветку только названием тега.

Comment: Блин, ну он конечно дает...
А улучшить регуляку никак...
Хоть бери учи питон и API ST3... и сам пиши))))

Comment: Поскольку регулярка имени тега отвечает ещё и за сопоставление тегов, её подмена сломает вообще всё к хренам :)

Comment: Ну так, нужно писать с нуля будет))))

Comment: На самом деле нет. Я только что проверил своё предположение в комментариях и оно работает. Ну... на паре искусственных тестов. Сейчас проверю на чём-нибудь более тяжёлом.

Comment: А можно подробнее?

Comment: [Можно.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579898/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-sublime-text-3/580232?noredirect=1#comment770148_579898) Я напишу ответ, как только удовлетворюсь результататми.

Comment: `"ignore_threshold": true,` [**не забудьте**](https://toster.ru/q/348956#answer_874433) на чём-то тяжёлом поставить. Спасибо.

Answer (score -2):

Согласно [документации](https://facelessuser.github.io/BracketHighlighter/customize/#configuring-highlight-style) плагина, в bh_core.sublime-settings вы можете поменять режим отображения для нужных вам знаков (скобок, слэшей, точек).

В вашем случае, я думаю, это "angle", параметр "style" должен быть "highlight". Выглядит как-то так, попробуйте поиграть с параметрами

```
"angle": {
    "icon": "angle_bracket",
    "color": "brackethighlighter.angle",
    "style": "highlight"
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что я уже 2 дня колдую с этим модулем)))<br>

Comment: И я уже пробовал баловаться со стилями и так далее, и оно не помогает(

Comment: @php_array выкладывайте содержимое вашего файла настроек в вопросе, где вы играетесь со стилями, будем смотреть. будем сравнивать с доками

Comment: отредактировал вопрос,
это те манипуляции, которые я делал с самим Bracket​Highlighter

Comment: Это не про парные теги, а про парные угловые скобочки, и не имеет отношения к проблеме, с которой столкнулся ТС.

Comment: Вот, еще пробовал сделать как он советует: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/549002/224777

Comment: @D-side если вы поставили минус моему ответу, пройдите, пожалуйста, в документацию и ознакомьтесь. раздел кастомизации предусматривает выделение указанных знаков вместе с тегом

Comment: @php_array вы меня вынуждаете поставить st и попробовать самому)

Comment: @while1pass я знаком с документацией, я самолично пользуюсь этим пакетом и уже чётко указал, почему этот ответ не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу.

Comment: @D-side значит пишите ответ, я пока себе st поставлю

Comment: То, что этот ответ неверный, не означает, что у меня есть верный :) Я описал ситуацию в комментариях к вопросу.

Comment: **1.** Минус прежде всего за ответ «попробуйте поиграть». Между «мне кажется, что проблема с $софтом разрешится после $определённых действий» и «проблема с $софтом разрешилась» часто бывает множество подводных камней. Поэтому я всегда стараюсь воспроизвожу решение у себя прежде чем его публиковать. // **Что неправильно в этом ответе:** // **2.** Как сказали выше, изменять значения необходимо у параметра `tag`, а не `angle`. // **3.** Если подставить значение `highlight`, теги выделятся [**вот так**](http://i.imgur.com/rwuthql.png), тогда как автору нужен `outline`, который захватывает скобки.

Comment: **4.** я «поиграл»: подставлял [**все приведённые в документации значения к параметру `style`**](http://facelessuser.github.io/BracketHighlighter/customize/#configuring-highlight-style) — проблему это не решило. // Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных спасибо за искрометный комментарий, прошлой ночью вопрос стоял по другому с меньшим количеством уточнений. я ответил на него, исходя из указанных данных. st у меня не стоит, поэтому я бегло ознакомился с документацией и указал раздел кастомизации тегов, предположив, какие параметры нужно изменить. причем направление задал верно, а сейчас мы в итоге имеем мой заминусованный ответ к изменившемуся вопросу.

Comment: @СашаЧерных "попробуйте поиграть с параметрами", адекватный призыв к внимательному изучению документации в указанном месте, тем более вы сами предлагаете "экспериментировать со значениями параметров", будьте последовательны

Comment: В документации решения нет. "Попробуйте поиграть" на ответ тоже не тянет, от силы на комментарий.

Comment: ну, все. я умываю руки, мы начинаем искать фразы в контексте, которые кому-то не нравятся

Comment: Как только вы покажете, где именно в вашем ответе содержится работающее решение, я сразу же сниму свой минус :)