# Автоматическое изменение цвета у заданных слов в Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Необходимо, чтобы, например, набор символов `тест` в документах, открытых Sublime Text 3, всегда был оранжевого цвета; `<пример>` — красного, `@stackoverflow` — синего и т. п. . Не [подсветка](https://github.com/seanliang/HighlightWords), а именно другой цвет. Особо не имеет значения, сразу во всех цветовых схемах или же только [в той, которой пользуюсь](http://colorsublime.com/theme/Espresso_Libre).

Цель — хочется простенький [ToDo-менеджер](http://www.3dnews.ru/920530) прямо в Sublime Text, где разноцветные слова выполняли бы роль тегов, по которым легко ориентироваться. ToDo-плагин [PlainTasks](https://github.com/aziz/PlainTasks) не устраивает.

Возможно ли так сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение проверено в Windows XP и новейшей (на март 2016) версии редактора — Sublime Text 3 Build 3103.

1. Если установлена более старая версия Sublime Text 3, [скачиваем Build 3103](https://download.sublimetext.com/Sublime%20Text%20Build%203103.zip) с официального сайта, для 64-битной Windows и других операционных систем ссылки [тут](https://www.sublimetext.com/3).
2. В верхнем меню Sublime Text 3 открываем `Preferences` ► `Browse Packages...` , в папке `User` создаём файл `ToDo Manager.sublime-settings`, куда копируем следующее содержимое:

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
---
# http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html
name: ToDo Manager
file_extensions:
  - task
scope: text.task
contexts:
  main:
    - match: (?i)@Работа
      scope: meta.work
    - match: (?i)@Проект1
      scope: meta.project1
    - match: (?i)@Срочно
      scope: meta.avral
```

Где `ToDo Manager` — имя файла подсветки, которое должно совпадать с именем до расширения `.sublime-settings` только что созданного нами в папке `User` файла; `task` — расширение файлов, при открытии которых программой Sublime Text 3 будет функционировать наша подсветка, должно совпадать со словом после `scope: text.` в следующей строке (не поставил расширение todo, поскольку оно уже зарезервировано [плагином](https://github.com/aziz/PlainTasks) ).

Если теги нашего ToDo-менеджера будут иметь вид `@'Название тега'`, вписываем их, как в примере выше, желаете по-другому — используйте вместо `@` свой вариант. Взамен `work`, `project1` и `avral` можно вписать любые значения, лишь бы они совпадали с дальнейшей вставкой.

3. Как лучше всего подобрать цветовую схему для Sublime Text 3. Переходим на страницу онлайн-сервиса [TmTheme Editor](https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/local/), в левом меню выбираем предпочтительную цветовую схему, настраиваем её в зависимости от наших пожеланий. Доступен предпросмотр цветов и подсветки для различных языков разметки/программирования:

[TmTheme Editor http://pokit.org/get/img/4ba225a894915a99fbc8dacf4367e80b.jpg](http://pokit.org/get/img/4ba225a894915a99fbc8dacf4367e80b.jpg)

`Save` ► `Download` — сохраняем файл в папку, где хранятся цветовые схемы: `Preferences` ► `Browse Packages...` ► `User`. Переключение на схему осуществляется посредством `Preferences` ► `Color Scheme` ► `User`.

4. Перед следующими строками в конце файла цветовой схемы

   ```
   </array>
   <key>uuid</key>
   <string>6B90703E-4E4B-43C8-9D32-921BEDF6D725</string>
   <key>colorSpaceName</key>
   <string>sRGB</string>
   <key>semanticClass</key>
   <string>theme.dark.espresso_libre</string>
   ```

вставляем текст:

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>work</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.work</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>background</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>Yellow</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>project1</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.project1</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>background</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#00FF00</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>avral</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.avral</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>background</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>Red</string>
     </dict>
```

Значения должны совпадать с теми, что мы вписывали в файл `ToDo Manager.sublime-settings`. Между тегами `<string></string>` вводим цвета. Лучше прописывать их в [HEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet), а не [`X11 colors`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names), поскольку в Sublime Text 3 могут некорректно отображаться как минимум цвета `aqua`, `fuchsia` и `lime`.

Для подсветки цветов в форматах HEX и RGB служит плагин [ColorHighlighter](https://github.com/Monnoroch/ColorHighlighter). Самый простой способ установки — через [Package Control](http://forum.sublimetext.ru/index.php?topic=6.0): в Sublime Text 3 нажимаем <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> ► в открывшуюся строку вводим `Package Control: Install Package` ► среди всплывающих вариантов выбираем соответствующий пункт ► теперь вводим в ту же строку `Color Highlighter` ► среди всплывающих вариантов выбираем соответствующий пункт ► плагин установлен.

5. Создаём файл с расширением `.task` . Открываем его нашим Sublime Text 3, выполняем: `View ► Syntax ► Open all with current extension as... ► User ► ToDo Manager`. Пробуем в этом же файле, что у нас получилось:

[image: Пример работы самодельного ToDo-менеджера в Sublime Text 3]

Всё, раскрашиваем содержимое `task`-файлов, как душе угодно. Спасибо за подробное объяснение ув-мому [Мэтту Моррисону](http://mattdmo.com/).